# Saves replace newer saves with older ones when Online after being in Offline Mode?

Tags: steam-cloud

A few times, now, I've made progress in a game while in Offline Mode, because my flaky internet makes Steam give me that option from time to time.

That's fine.

But, if I boot Steam up again in Online Mode later, the progress I've made has reverted to an older version, presumably the one on Steam Cloud.

Is there a fix? I'm very perplexed at how an older file is overwriting a newer one.

Comment: IT's likely the saves being loaded from a different location - Offline saves would be stored on your pc, and online saves would be stored in the cloud somewhere, so when you go back online, it changes the location of the save files.

Comment: @Ben - I only play these games on 1 PC, though?